# Error while 'pod init' in macOS Catalina "`pwd': Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)"

Tags: ruby, macos, cocoa, cocoapods, macos-catalina

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    35: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    34: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    33: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
    32: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    31: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    30: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    29: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    28: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    27: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    26: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    25: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    24: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    23: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    22: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    21: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    20: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    19: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    18: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    17: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    16: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    15: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/i18n.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    13: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/i18n-0.9.5/lib/i18n.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `load_native_extensions'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `each'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `block in load_native_extensions'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:62:in `try_load_c_extension'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': cannot load such file -- concurrent/concurrent_ruby_ext (LoadError)
    46: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    45: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    44: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
    43: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    42: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    41: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    40: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    39: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    38: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    37: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    36: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    35: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    34: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    33: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    32: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    31: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    30: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    29: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    28: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    27: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    26: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/i18n.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    25: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    24: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    23: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/i18n-0.9.5/lib/i18n.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    22: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    21: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    19: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    18: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    17: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `load_native_extensions'
    15: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `each'
    14: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `block in load_native_extensions'
    13: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:62:in `try_load_c_extension'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:156:in `require'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:161:in `rescue in require'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:204:in `try_activate'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:996:in `find_by_path'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:996:in `find'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:996:in `each'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:997:in `block in find_by_path'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:39:in `compatible?'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:7:in `bundler_version'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:22:in `bundler_version_with_reason'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:73:in `lockfile_version'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:85:in `lockfile_contents'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:85:in `pwd': Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)
```

Comment: Basically this issue is due to the fact that you are using the system ruby instead of a ruby version mananger like rbenv/rvm which will install gems in `~/` (your user directory) instead of  `/Library/` which causes permission issues.

Comment: I installed RVM and then install cocoapods , now when I am going to hit pod init at my Xcode project directory it causes error like.                   /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `pwd': Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)